# xlsx writer causes error with excel upon opening

Tags: python, vba, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm currently using xlsx writer to transfer information from a plain text file to excel. However, after the excel document is created, most of the time I can't open it. I get the following error: 
"We're sorry, but Excel has run into an error that is preventing it from working correctly. Excel will need to be closed as a result.

Would you like us to repair now?"

Then when I select repair now it simply closes Excel. Sometimes it will work and I can view the file.

Here is the plain text file for reference:

```
"DOT_NUMBER","LEGAL_NAME","DBA_NAME","CARRIER_OPERATION","HM_FLAG","PC_FLAG","PHY_STREET","PHY_CITY","PHY_STATE","PHY_ZIP","PHY_COUNTRY","MAILING_STREET","MAILING_CITY","MAILING_STATE","MAILING_ZIP","MAILING_COUNTRY","TELEPHONE","FAX","EMAIL_ADDRESS","MCS150_DATE","MCS150_MILEAGE","MCS150_MILEAGE_YEAR","ADD_DATE","OIC_STATE","NBR_POWER_UNIT","DRIVER_TOTAL"
10000,"POWELL DISTRIBUTING CO INC","","A","N","N","9125 N BURRAGE AVE","PORTLAND","OR","97217-6961","US","P O BOX 17160","PORTLAND","OR","97217-0160","US","(503) 289-5558","(503) 735-0100","","06-DEC-16","20000","2015","01-JUN-74","OR","1","1"
1000002,"NEW JERSEY BOOM & ERECTORS INC","","A","N","N","120 SANS DRIVE","HENRYVILLE","PA","18332","US","120 SANS DRIVE","HENRYVILLE","PA","18332","US","(570) 620-1546","(570) 620-1517","GAIL@NJBOOM.COM","06-JAN-16","243647","2015","22-JAN-02","PA","1","1"
1000004,"RAY TRUCKING LLC","","C","N","N","218 PEACHTREE ST","WARWICK","GA","31796","US","PO BOX 281","WARWICK","GA","31796","US","(229) 535-4140","","MONTOYARAY@YMAIL.COM","19-OCT-16","83000","2015","22-JAN-02","GA","2","2"
1000008,"GUERRERA LANDSCAPING LLC","","C","N","N","164 NUT PLAINS RD","GUILFORD","CT","06437-2138","US","164 NUT PLAINS RD","GUILFORD","CT","06437-2138","US","(203) 453-6693","","","25-MAR-06","30000","2005","22-JAN-02","CT","4","3"
1000009,"REINHARD CORP","","C","N","N","1647 REINHARD RD","CHESHIRE","CT","06410","US","1647 REINHARD RD","CHESHIRE","CT","06410","US","(203) 272-2869","","","11-APR-06","2000","2005","22-JAN-02","CT","1","1"
1000010,"DELUXE MOTOR COMPANY INC","DELUXE HARLEY DAVIDSON-BUELL","A","N","N","3300 CONESTOGA DR","CASPER","WY","82718","US","3300 CONESTOGA DR","GILLETTE","WY","82718","US","(307) 687-2001","(307) 687-0245","JACKJR59@GMAIL.COM","26-OCT-16","50000","2014","22-JAN-02","WY","8","3"
1000012,"CENTRAL HEATING & AIR INC","","C","N","N","600 S CHARLOTTE","SIOUX FALLS","SD","57103-2614","US","600 S CHARLOTTE","SIOUX FALLS","SD","57103-2614","US","(605) 371-3076","(605) 339-4409","CENTRALHEATING@MIDCONETWORK.COM","26-OCT-10","89918","2008","22-JAN-02","SD","9","5"
1000593,"SIGNAL GATES INC","","B","N","N","1800 S 5TH AVE","TUCSON","AZ","85713-5713","US","1800 S 5TH AVE","TUCSON","AZ","85713-5713","US","(520) 628-3199","(520) 628-3620","KIM@SIGNALGATES.COM","01-NOV-13","100000","2013","24-JAN-02","AZ","7","9"
```

And the code (updated):

```
import xlsxwriter

filename = "minitest.txt"
file = open(filename, 'r')
print("file opened")

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Carriers.xlsx")
worksheetA = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheetB = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheetC = workbook.add_worksheet()

rowA = 0
rowB = 0
rowC = 0

for line in file:
    line = line.replace('"', ' ')
    entry = line.split(",")
    col = 0

    if entry[3] == " A ":
        for item in entry:
            worksheetA.write(rowA, col, item)
            col += 1

        rowA += 1

    if entry[3] == " B ":
        for item in entry:
            worksheetB.write(rowB, col, item)
            col += 1

        rowB += 1

    if entry[3] == " C ":
        for item in entry:
            worksheetC.write(rowC, col, item)
            col += 1

        rowC += 1

workbook.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: `row` should not be defined within your `while` loop.

Comment: Also, the broken file, can you open it in Notepad/TextEdit ?

Comment: Changed the rows thing, and I can open it in Notepad. It is a bunch of random characters with some distinguishable elements such as the work sheet. The only idea I have as to why am I getting the error is that the workbook is still loaded in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your issue. I simplified your program a bit by removing the `main()` and the `running` loop and I moved the `row` increment into the if statment. As follows:

```
import xlsxwriter

filename = "minitest.txt"
file = open(filename, 'r')
print("file opened")

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Carriers.xlsx")
worksheetA = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
for line in file:
    line = line.replace('"', ' ')
    entry = line.split(",")
    col = 0
    if entry[3] == " A ":
        print(entry[3])
        for item in entry:
            print(row, "|", col)
            print(item)
            worksheetA.write(row, col, item)
            col += 1

        row += 1

workbook.close()
file.close()
```

I then ran it with you sample text file and it produces the expected output without warning:

[image]

**Update**: I ran the updated program and didn't see any issue either:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate it! not sure what was going on with mine then. Oh well!

Comment: I updated it to separate them to three different sheets and now I'm encountering the same problem (updated code in original post)

Comment: @Jordan Murray I don't see any issue with the updated version either, see my update above. What version of XlsxWriter and what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm going to have to do some trouble shooting with my microsoft office. I've now realized there is nothing wrong with the code in either but with my Mircrosoft office giving me the same error prompt no matter what I try to open. Thank you again!